# docker volume and VOLUME inside Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm confused with what is different between creating `docker volume create my-vol` and `VOLUME ["/var/www"]`.

My understanding is:

1) `docker volume create my-vol` creates a persistent volume on our machine and each container could be linked to `my-vol`.

2) `VOLUME ["/var/www"]` creates a volume inside its container.

> And when I create another container, I could link `my-vol` as follows:
>   when running a container
>
> ```
> $ docker run -d --name devtest --mount source=myvol2,target=/app nginx:latest
> ```
>
> At that time, if I added `VOLUME ["/var/www"]` in my Dockerfile, all data of this docker file will be stored in both `myvol2` and `/var/www`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Dockerfile `VOLUME` command says two things:

1. If the operator doesn't explicitly mount a volume on the specific container directory, create an anonymous one there anyways.
2. No Dockerfile step will ever be able to make further changes to that directory tree.

As an operator, you can mount a volume (either a named volume or a host directory) into a container with the `docker run -v` option.  You can mount it over any directory in the container, regardless of whether or not there was a `VOLUME` declared for it in the Dockerfile.

(Since you can use `docker run -v` regardless of whether or not you declare a `VOLUME`, and it has confusing side effects, I would generally avoid declaring `VOLUME` in Dockerfiles.)

Just like in ordinary Linux, only one thing can be (usefully) mounted on any given directory.  With the setup you describe, data will be stored in the `myvol2` you create and mount, and it will be visible in `/var/www` in the container, but the data will only actually be stored in one place.  If you deleted and recreated the container without the volume mount the data would not be there any more.

Answer (score 0):

There are two types of persistent storage used in Docker,the first one is Docker Volumes and the second one is bind mounts. The differebce between them is that volumes are internal to Docker and stored in the Docker store (which is usually all under /var/lib/docker) and bind mounts use a physical location on your machine to store persistent data.

If you want to use a Docker Volume for nginx:

> docker volume create nginx-vol
>
> docker run -d --name devtest -v nginx-vol:/usr/share/nginx/html nginx

If you want to use a bind mount:

> docker run -d --name devtest -v [path]:/usr/share/nginx/html nginx

[path] is the location in which you want to store the container's data.

Comment: kinda useful, but please describe more detail related to my question next time, then so your answer will be correct one. Thanks much.

Comment: Actually it was my first day and answer on stackoverflow, i'll make sure to put more efforts on answers next time, always welcome.