# Why docker gitlab/gitlab-runner use "/etc/gitlab-runner" and "/home/gitlab-runner" as VOLUME?

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

From https://hub.docker.com/r/gitlab/gitlab-runner/dockerfile:

```
VOLUME ["/etc/gitlab-runner", "/home/gitlab-runner"]
```

I have read [Understanding "VOLUME" instruction in DockerFile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41935435/understanding-volume-instruction-in-dockerfile) and [docker volume and VOLUME inside Dockerfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53901320/docker-volume-and-volume-inside-dockerfile), however, I still cannot figure why does this image specify these two paths as VOLUME.

Comment: I assume this maps each of these folders to identical folders in the container. However, it looks like from your answer link, a Docker container would still require host directories to be specified in the `docker run` command in order for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

The [`VOLUME` command](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#volume) in the Dockerfile exposes these directories as `VOLUMES`. Meaning it will auto-create volumes on `docker run` to persist the data inside the container(s).

Since containers are suppose to be [stateless](https://blog.docker.com/2016/03/containers-are-not-vms/) you want to persistent configuration and e.g. build-cache on the host.